# Social Login with OAuth in Android WebView

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

The social login(Facebook/Google), does not work in a classic WebView which access a website.
I have tried different approaches but the final result is always the same (different errors).
For Facebook I receive, now: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

This is my original code:

```
package find.yourbets.NerdyTips;

import android.os.Bundle;

import find.yourbets.NerdyTips.R;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.clearCache(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://nerdytips.com");
        webView.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Any ideas?